# How to check if a query (CRUD) was made on a database

Tags: sql-server

I'm sorry for the title but I have a problem which I can't sum up in a sentence.

I have a database with 100 tables and probably a thousand columns. Now, every time something changes in the database, for example:

1. New table is created
2. New column is created (Insert)
3. Column is updated (Update)
4. Column is deleted (Deleted)
5. And a column is read (Read)

I would like to know.

From what I have read there are 3 options but I have an issue with all three:

1. SQL Profiler (soon to be obsolete)
2. Extended Events (too complex for me)
3. Open MSSQL query field and go crazy

For now, I am trying to go with the third. I am hoping to use `sys.object` or `sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats` and any other table to get what I want.

So, my question is: Do you think there is a better alternative or not?

Comment: see [SQL Server DDL Triggers to Track All Database Changes](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2085/sql-server-ddl-triggers-to-track-all-database-changes/) by Aaron Bertrand.

Comment: _And a column is read (Read)_ Really? This would involve vast quantities of repetitive information. If the general approach to selecting rows is "select * from ..." you will likely find this particular information mostly useless.

Comment: I'll also add that you likely seek information on **rows**, not **columns**. Schema changes (e.g., column is added or deleted) should be source-controlled. CDC might help with the "who changes what" information. Perhaps you need to think a bit more about your goal since it's not quite clear to me what you seek.

Answer (score 0):

I would have thought that the Audit functionality would meet your requirements.
If you search for SQL Server Audit you'll get lots of hits - it is very configurable but too big to describe fully here.
Have you looked at that ?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/163465)

Comment: The question was :-
Do you think there is a better alternative or not?
I recommended SQL Server Audit - I fail to see how that is not a useful answer.

Comment: You're asking a question in your answer, which makes this seem more like a comment than an answer.  I would suggest adding details around how and why the SQL Server Audit feature would solve the problem at hand.  I'd at least add some links to the MIcrosoft docs, and probably a quick write-up about how to set it up.

Comment: You could flag this quiestion, because of "tip of an Iceberg" question, but asking for clarification should be done by a comment.